# the child of Gridlayout goes out of boundary

Tags: android, button

i m trying to produce a layout with buttons having 5 columns and 6 rows. while the buttons in rows match perfectly with boundary but the last column goes out of boundary of the gridlayout. how to resize the buttons so the columns adjust and fill within the boundary of gridlayout?

Comment: could you post your code here

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout />
```

instead of

```
<GridLayout />
```

in app level cradle file make sure you have added

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.2.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
```

Comment: my GridLayout is inside RelativeLayout. So can i do that?

Comment: i have tried this one but there is error which says "Missing classes".